# How do you eliminate overall image css to a single div?

Tags: css, image

As an example I'm trying to create a thumbnail, but my automatic img css as listed below is applied

```
img, img a {
border: none;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

I can't make sense of it in my mind for some reason. I know the syntax is probably simple, but I can't seem to remember it.
Thanks
Chris

Comment: I'm not sure what your HTML is - please post that too. And `img a` can't exist because there can't be an a tag inside an img tag...

Comment: I'm not sure what other code you're referring to. The image is a standard img code. nothing else added. I'm also not sure what you mean by img a can't exist. Is this not proper? Thanks so much for the quick response.

Comment: `img a` would select an `a` tag nested within an `img` tag. An `img` element *cannot* contain any other elements, therefore it will never match any elements. Presumably you meant to target an `img` element within an `a` element (`a img`)?

Comment: Okay, so I think I got out of that the fact that a is not necessary within the css for IMG? Assuming that is no longer there and I want to change the margins specifically for an image within a div and separate from all other images throughout the site. How could I approach this.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question in a clearer manner?

Comment: @HireLogo: If you want to select any image that is a descendant of any div, use `div img`.

Comment: You the man Bobby Jack...I tried .img for some reason instead of img with no ".". Thanks for the quick responses everyone. I knew it was something dumb I was messing up on.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can not add margin to your images is because img elements are, by default, inline. It means you can not give them dimensions, or add margin from the bottom or top (and some other stuff you should probably read about).

This means that in order to give img element margin from top or bottom, you need to declare it as a block, or rather inline-block. This is achieved using

```
img { display: inline-block; }
```

Then you can add away your margins, and viola:

```
img { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to style all images a certain way, then exclude images within a certain container div?  If your container div is called #wrapper, then do something like this:

```
#wrapper img,
#wrapper a img /* assuming that's what you meant rather than img a */
{
  /* undo what you did above for images inside #wrapper */
  margin-top: 0;   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Such loose selectors for img can be troublesome because images are used all the time in different contexts.  I prefer to style only images that are inside a #content div, or similar.